# Organize data from a bookkeeping system

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with a bookkeeping system like these data below (the grouping and reconciled column doesn't exist):

```
Date        num (pk)    document    supplier    debit       credit      balance     GROUPING   RECONCILED
06/12/2016  4302458     26933       SUPPLIER_1  4,35                    4,35                    FALSE
06/12/2016  4302456     26933       SUPPLIER_1  19,12                   19,12                   FALSE
13/12/2016  4330098     27023       SUPPLIER_1  5,79                    5,79        1 or 1      TRUE
13/12/2016  4330096     27023       SUPPLIER_1  25,45                   25,45       1 or 1      TRUE
13/12/2016  4330095     27023       SUPPLIER_1              1.157,00    -1.157,00   1 or 1      TRUE
13/12/2016  4330591     223130      SUPPLIER_1  1.115,76                1.115,76    1 or 1      TRUE
13/12/2016  4330588                 SUPPLIER_1  10,00                   10,00       1 or 1      TRUE
19/12/2016  4342835     27108       SUPPLIER_1              1.294,00    -1.294,00   2 or 1      TRUE
19/12/2016  4342838     27108       SUPPLIER_1  6,47                    6,47        2 or 1      TRUE
19/12/2016  4342836     27108       SUPPLIER_1  28,47                   28,47       2 or 1      TRUE
22/12/2016  4366603     223841      SUPPLIER_1  1.259,06                1.259,06    2 or 1      TRUE
26/12/2016  4371509     27200       SUPPLIER_1  14,61                   14,61       3 or 1      TRUE
26/12/2016  4371511     27200       SUPPLIER_1  3,32                    3,32        3 or 1      TRUE
26/12/2016  4371508     27200       SUPPLIER_1              664,00      -664,00     3 or 1      TRUE
29/12/2016  4376366     224598      SUPPLIER_1  646,07                  646,07      3 or 1      TRUE
```

So, I have some other data from different suppliers on different dates not sorted and I need to identify the values by suppliers where debit sum and credit sum total to zero (balance sum is equal zero), like the reconciled column.

I need to do a function that read each data and can sumarize the debit value and credit value then when these values are equal, identify with reconciled = `true`. The values that can't total, these should be identified with reconciled=`false`.

The grouping column is just a example where the balance is equal zero. It doesn't matter for me.

Comment: So, it sounds like, when this set is ordered by date, for each supplier you want to group the records when the balance hit's zero. When a balance hit's zero, starting from history, and working forward, that's a group, and the new group starts again until zero is hit?

Comment: It's something like this but it isn't just this. Because ordering by date, you can see the two first records don't combine with no other record to total zero. So, go ahead and the third record can combine with other to total zero until the seventh record or in this case until the last record from this supplier. I don't have any correspondence to group except the supplier.

Comment: @JNevill is there any solution for this? I've tried some others things but none worked correctly. 
I did a function that set true case `sum(debit) over (partition by supplier, SUBSTRING(num,1,3)) = sum(credit) over (partition by supplier, SUBSTRING(num,1,3))` or case `sum(debit) over (partition by supplier, date) = sum(credit) over (partition by supplier, date)` or case `sum(debit) over (partition by supplier, document) = sum(credit) over (partition by supplier, document)` but it isn't the better way and it doesn't return the expected value.